# Rails runner script not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Any ideas why this doesn't work, I get a `NoMethodError`when I try and run the code below via `rails runner`.

Maybe I am calling the rails runner incorrectly, sorry new to Rails!

File location:

```
/app/scripts/data_import.rb
```

Command:

```
rails runner -e development DataImport.say_hi
```

Error:

```
undefined method `say_hi' for DataImport:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Code:

```
class DataImport

  def say_hi
    puts "hi"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are calling an instance method on the class, so it's undefined. Try making your method a class method instead:

```
class DataImport
  def self.say_hi
    puts "hi"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Change it to

```
class DataImport
  def self.say_hi
    puts "hi"
  end
end
```

Since you're accessing it as a class method and not a method on an instance of the class, you need the `self` to declare the method as a class method.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the already mentioned transformation of the instance method into a method of the singleton class is to create an object of the existing class and call the instance method in your runner:

```
rails runner -e development "import = DataImport.new; import.say_hi"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, Many friends already Posted that.

```
class DataImport
  def self.say_hi
   puts "hi"
  end
end
```

And the reason is, If you have a class and method without self. , You can't call the class like ClassName.method. You can call like this If only the method is a self method of that class.

Otherwise you can call like `ClassName.new.method`.

In your Problem, You can call like

```
DataImport.new.say_hi
```

And the Class remains the same as you written.