# Undefined method in runner

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, runner

So I've been trying to test the following simple script title procedure.rb

```
class Procedure < ActiveRecord::Base
  def fetch__records
    selection = connection.execute("SELECT * From users  WHERE name = test AND password = password")

    if (selection != nil)
      puts "It works."
    else
      puts "It fails."
    end
  end
end
```

Which just sends a simple SQL select statement to a users table and And yet every time I run

```
rails runner "Procedure.fetch_records"
```

I get the following error

```
  undefined method `fetch_records' for Procedure(Table doesn't exist):Class (NoMethodError)
```

I took a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053515/rails-runner-script-not-working) and changed it that fetch_records is defined as

```
def self.fetch_records
```

But I still received the same error. Why is it saying fetch_records in undefined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two underscore characters in def fetch__records.

Comment: I have problems with plurals, kick myself every time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your method definition has two underscores while you are calling only one:

```
def fetch__records
```

And

```
rails runner "Procedure.fetch_records"
```

Change either the def to `fetch_records` or the runner to `fetch__records`